# JavaScript Object for..in loop

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```js
function person(name, age) {
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;
 this.changeName = changeName;

 function changeName(name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
}

my = new person("Ying", 21);
for (i in my) {
 document.write(my[i] + " ");
}
```

Result:

> Ying 21 function changeName(name) { this.name = name; }

why does it output the changeName() method?

Comment: Why shouldn't it?  It's a member of your `person` object.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the changeName property, you're using the + operator on a function, so it gets implicitly converted to a string. You might want something like this instead:

```
if (typeof my[i] !== 'function') document.write(my[i] + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript methods aren't special. They are members of the object like any other. If you want to ignore them you can do this:

```
my = new person("Ying", 21);
for (i in my) {
    if (typeof my[i] !== 'function') document.write(my[i] + " ");
}
```

This skips over keys whose members are functions.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a constructor function every thing that you define within the function gets attached to the constructed object because of javascript being function scoped. So your function is associated with the **this**. Hence the problem that you face.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function person(name, age) {
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;
 this.changeName = changeName;

 function changeName(name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
}

my = new person("Ying", 21);
for (i in my) {
    if (typeof my[i] !== 'function') document.write(my[i] + " ");
}
```